# Lighttpd: What are these multiple log files?

Tags: log-files, lighttpd

I went into the log folder of my lighttpd server and I found several files:

> access.log    access.log.4.gz 
>   error.log    error.log.2.gz
>   access.log.1  deluxeorganics
>   error.log.1

I was wondering if the server is creating log.1 log.2 files (and compressing them) to store the log history in separate files.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like your log files are being rotated and compressed by [**logrotate**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: @Patrick: You can search for logrotate config file something like: /etc/logrotate.d/lighttpd